# Subqueries with select in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Team,

I have an issue here, have 2 temporary table a & b with value as 5 & 6 for the respective column like a.ref1 & b.ref2.

I am trying to get these values into another SQL like

```
"select c.col1, d.col1,d.col2 from c join d on a.id=d.id where d.col1=(schema_name).a.ref1  or 
d.col2=(schema_name).b.ref2"
```

I get error like

```
"Invalid table alias or column reference "
```

. any thoughts, why it behaving like this. I tried with select query to pass the temp table values but this does not work in hive .Any further assistance would be appreciated

Comment: You are joining c and d but using a.id=d.id

Comment: correction, the join is between c and d on c.id=d.id... And I do not want to join the temp table a & b here on the final pass (not sure granularity will change or not) but need to pass those temp table value here for d table col1 & col2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you can do this by using something called Common Table Expression, This will make your query perform better.

It would look like this:

```
WITH
    refined_d AS
    (
        SELECT
            d.id,
            d.col1,
            d.col2
        FROM
            d
        INNER JOIN
            (schema_name).a
        ON
            ( (schema_name).a.ref1 = d.col1)
        INNER JOIN
            (schema_name).b
        ON
            ( ( schema_name).b.ref2 = d.col2)
    )
SELECT
    c.col1,
    d.col1,
    d.col2
FROM
    c
JOIN
    refined_d d
ON
    c.id=d.id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am bit new to CTE, I recreated the same way and run the query but syntactically nothing wrong but NO results returned... any suggestions?

Comment: You need to debug the query, mostly because of the inner joins.
I would start by debugging the first part. 
`        SELECT
            d.id,
            d.col1,
            d.col2
        FROM
            d
        INNER JOIN
            (schema_name).a
        ON
            ( (schema_name).a.ref1 = d.col1)
        INNER JOIN
            (schema_name).b
        ON
            ( ( schema_name).b.ref2 = d.col2)
  `
make sure it returns results.

Comment: Absolutely, I did debugging with "with" pass, That should result me value, I had some datatype conversion issue as a.ref1 & b.ref2 are double and d.col1 & d.col2 are bigint. I did type cast the value like  SELECT d.id, d.col1, d.col2 FROM d INNER JOIN (schema_name).a ON  (schema_name).a.ref1 as  = cast(d.col1 as double) INNER JOIN (schema_name).b ON ( ( schema_name).b.ref2 = cast(d.col2 as double) still no results.... will dig in further... doing vice versa type conversion too...

Comment: Can you update the question with the DDL of your tables?

Comment: Table a Create table schema_name.a as select a.ref1 from table E where E.type='X'

Comment: Ignore the earlier comment  
Table a "Create table schema_name.a as select a.ref1 from table E where E.type='X' "                                                                                                        Table b "Create table schema_name.b as select b.ref2 from table F where F.type='Y'  " and Table d is a existing table with columns including d.col1 and d.col2 . Table a.ref1 has value 5.0 and table b.ref2 has value 6.0 where as d.col1 has 5 and d.col2 has 6... I just manually computed (hard coded the value) the value, it giving me results but this needs to fixed...any suggestions

Comment: I cannot see what is in Table E?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190106/discussion-between-ma28-and-awadodeh).